# ArcGIS JS-API, zoom to extent

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to move the zoom to an extent.

I have this var:

```
var extentGeo = esri.geometry.webMercatorToGeographic(map.extent);
console.log('extentGeo', extentGeo);
// { cache: undefined
// spatialReference: {wkid: 4326}
// type: "extent"
// xmax: -70.60487747064096
// xmin: -70.67328452935668
// ymax: -33.42183884025852
// ymin: -33.48435589231657 }
```

Is there a way to move the map using those `extent.xmin`, `extent.ymin`, `extent.xmax`, and `extent.ymax` ?

Comment: Which api version are you using? V3 and v4 has different methods for that

Comment: Getting extent from the map and setting it to the same extent will not show any change. Can you explain more about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [map.setExtent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#setextent)